# existence of a non-negative smooth function on a neighborhood of point on a boundary of a smooth manifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be an n-dimensional manifold with boundary and let $x \in \partial X$. Show that there exists a smooth non-negative function $f$ on some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f(z)=0$ iff $z \in \partial U$, with $0$ be the regular value of $f$.

---

Could someone help me in solving this problem? thank you.

Comment: The most elementary solution is to let $U$ be a coordinate chart for the point $x\in\partial X$ and use the definition of a manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll denote the manifold by $M$. I assume you want to take $x$ as a boundary point (?).

Denote by $n$ the interior unit normal along the boundary (on a neighbourhood of some point, if you want to do this locally)

If you know that the exponentional map 
$$\partial M \times [0,\varepsilon ): (x,t)\mapsto \exp_x(t n(x))$$ 
is a diffeormorphism onto a neighbourhood of $\partial M$ in $M$ (for sufficiently small $\varepsilon >0$, if $\partial M$ is compact) then you know that (on that neighbourhood) 
$$f(\exp_x(t n(x))) := t$$
is well defined. It has the properties you asked for.

If $\partial M$ is not compact you need to modify this a bit or do this locally.

If you do not know about the exponential map you may work in local coordinates (which will result in a local result, which you could patch together to a global one using a partition of unity):

Consider a chart $$\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times [0,\infty) \rightarrow M$$
at the boundary and define 
$$h(x, t) = t$$
on 
$\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times [0,\infty)$
and let $f(p) = h(\varphi^{-1}(p))$